# UILabel isn't added to view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have two viewControllers where one of them contains a UILabel and a UIButton, and the other one a UITableView. When the UIButton in the first view is pressed the new ViewController is presented and when a row in the tableview is selected the tableview is dismissed and the UILabel in the first viewController should be updated so its text is the same as the cell name tapped in the tableview. 
Code:

In the first Viewcontroller:

```
- (void)changeTitleWithString:(NSString *)title
{
    UILabel* selected_station = [[UILabel alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 153+45, 231, 20)];
    [selected_station setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]];
    selected_station.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    selected_station.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", title];
    [self.view addSubview:selected_station];
    NSLog(@"%@", selected_station);
    NSLog(@"%@", title);
}
```

In second viewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.currentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row+1];

    NewViewController *viewCOntroller = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController changeTitleWithString:self.currentString];

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

The changeTitleWithString function is called and the string from tableview is successfully received in the function, but the UILabel won't show up. When I log out the UILabel (selected_station) it's not nil and its text is correct. Why doesn't the string show up on the view?

Comment: Please can you share the complete code , how click on button in frist view controller presents second view controller.

Comment: You're creating a new 'NewViewController' instance, but you're not displaying it, so it basically means you're doing nothing. You need a reference to the 1st view controller, a reference to the 'changeTitleWithString' method or similar, that's passed to the 2nd view controller.

Comment: You should write this comment as answer @trydis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look like you are referencing back to a previous allocated view controller (NewViewController). Rather you are allocating a new NewViewController.

A better approach might be to create a delegate protocol for the second view controller and make the NewViewController it's delegate --

So create a second view controller with a delegate property.

something like this

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentString;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
@end

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void) secondViewController:(SecondViewController*)secondViewController didChangeSelectionText:(NSString *)string;
@end
```

Now in the implementation of the SecondViewController do something like this

```
@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.currentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %ld", indexPath.row+1];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(secondViewController:didChangeSelectionText:)]) {
        [self.delegate secondViewController:self didChangeSelectionText:self.currentString];
    }
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Now in the implementation of the FirstViewController (your NewViewController) do something like this

```
@implementation FirstViewController

-(void) showSecondController
{
    SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController setDelegate:self]; // set this controller as the delegate
    // add the rest of the display code here
}

#pragma mark - SecondViewControllerDelegate Methods
-(void) secondViewController:(SecondViewController*)secondViewController didChangeSelectionText:(NSString *)string
{
    //change your text here
}
@end
```

This should be enough to get you pointed in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Im not sure if I understand you right though. Is the method declaration supposed to go into the .h-file in the second viewController or the NewViewController? And where should the method implementation go?

Comment: Sounds like the idea of delegates has you a bit confused. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/programmingwithobjectivec/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: I updated the answer with a more complete code example

Comment: Thanks for your awsome answer!

Answer (score 1):

In FirstViewController

```
- (void)changeTitleWithString:(NSString *)title :(UIView *)labelView
{
    UILabel* selected_station = [[UILabel alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 153+45, 231, 20)];
    [selected_station setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]];
    selected_station.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    selected_station.text = title;
    [labelView addSubview:selected_station];
    NSLog(@"%@", selected_station);
    NSLog(@"%@", title);
}
```

InSecondViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.currentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row+1];

    NewViewController *viewCOntroller = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController changeTitleWithString:self.currentString:self.view];

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

I hope it helps